# What's the better way to set an initial customer increment id?

Tags: eav, database

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440755/how-to-start-with-a-different-customer-id-in-magento) has two answers:

1. Set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `customer_entity` table.
2. Set the `increment_prefix` and `increment_last_id` for the `customer` entity in the `entity_store` table.

The second seems more correct (or at least more internally consistent with Magento), but it doesn't seem to work as far as I can tell. I've tried it multiple times with different configurations (with store_id 0, store_id 1 and setting the increment_per_store in `eav_entity_type` to 1 for customer), but each time I register as a new customer that customer's increment_id remains `NULL` and the entity_id increments from 1.

I'm reasonably sure the `AUTO_INCREMENT` approach will work, but given the fact that the `increment_last_id` works for order numbers, the second approach has a number of upvotes and seems more Magento-like I'd like to understand if that answer is more correct and I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the second of the two options will actually adjust the `increment_id` of the customer entity. The first method will change the `entity_id` field instead of the `increment_id`. So I think you are correct in favoring the second option.

As far as getting that method to work, Magento will only use the `eav_entity_store.increment_last_id` for the customer entities when a "Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID" setting is set to "Yes" in the config. See `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::setNewIncrementId` for where this check happens happens.

You can find this setting in the Magento admin at System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Create New Account Options -> Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID.